# what is best way to email login with custom model Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to make a login with a custom model, and i have tried many tutorials but nothing works for me. this is my model.

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from .choices import gender_choices, marital_status, districts

class UserRegister(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    termo_resp = models.BooleanField()

    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, max_length = 
             1,null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    marital_status = models.CharField(choices=marital_status, 
                     max_length = 1,null=True)
    districts = models.CharField(choices=districts, max_length = 
                20,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True)
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve based on the context of your question. However, creating a completely custom user model seems like a bad idea as you're going to lose a lot of support provided by other parts of django (not to mention you're storing raw passwords here). Try reading up on [django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/) and you'll probably find you'll be better off simply extending the user model.

Comment: I tried some of those examples in django authentication system but didn t worK,  I am using wizard forms..  Probably i am doing Something wrong. And now i dont have that code to show.

Comment: You should take some time to go through the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) and it will provide you with great examples of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Django's authentication system is a good point to start. you can simply import :

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User, PermissionMixin`

And in your model :

```
class UserModel(User,PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

So now go and create a form to be able construct a view for registering the users.
For example in the forms.py :
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta():
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        model = get_user_model()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "username"
        self.fields["email"].label = "email"
        self.fields["password1"].label = "pass"
        self.fields["password2"].label = "repeat pass"
```

You can use `generic views` and import `CreateView` to simply build a view for your form. To more read, [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/) is comprehensive Django own documentation.